# "Conditional formatting" in python for each dataset in a list appending the hex colors

Tags: python, python-2.7, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm looking for a way to do conditional formating based on numbers/percentages in a list, the output conditional formatting needs to be a hex color.

For example in the data below, there are 3 fully unique *"datasets"* which are generated by `row[0] + row[1]` each dataset would be analysed on it's own.

#### Data in List form (current layout)

```
[['UniqueData1', 'UniqueTest1', '13', '13.39%', '42.7%', 'Data'], ['UniqueData1', 'UniqueTest1', '14', '82%', '41.9%', 'Data'], ['UniqueData1', 'UniqueTest1', '18', '29.39%', '41%', 'Data'], ['UniqueData2', 'UniqueTest2', '22.3', '44.4%', '42.3%', 'Data'], ['UniqueData2', 'UniqueTest2', '4', '44.2%', '43.4%', 'Data'], ['UniqueData2', 'UniqueTest2', '4.1', '49%', '42.7%', 'Data'], ['UniqueData3', 'UniqueTest1', '4.45', '49.5%', '42.42%', 'Data'], ['UniqueData3', 'UniqueTest1', '4.29', '20%', '42.3%', 'Data'], ['UniqueData3', 'UniqueTest1', '4.22', '25%', '41.2%', 'Data']]
```

The wanted output would be for the above to appear with appended columns in each row of data for example:

```
['UniqueData3', 'UniqueTest1', '4.22', '25%', '41.2%', 'Data']
```

Might turn into:

```
['UniqueData3', 'UniqueTest1', '4.22', '25%', '41.2%', 'Data', '#d23f3f', '#db8a2e', '#4ea157']
```

Where `#d23f3f` relates to `4.22` and `#db8a2e` relates to `25%` and `#4ea157` relates to `41.2%` **Please note the hex colors are just examples**

Any ideas?

#### EDIT: Data in CSV form so that it's easily readable :)

```
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,13,13.39%,42.7%,Data
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,14,82%,41.9%,Data
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,18,29.39%,41%,Data
UniqueData2,UniqueTest2,22.3,44.4%,42.3%,Data
UniqueData2,UniqueTest2,4,44.2%,43.4%,Data
UniqueData2,UniqueTest2,4.1,49%,42.7%,Data
UniqueData3,UniqueTest1,4.45,49.5%,42.42%,Data
UniqueData3,UniqueTest1,4.29,20%,42.3%,Data
UniqueData3,UniqueTest1,4.22,25%,41.2%,Data
```

**For example in excel it would appear like:**

[image]

**Which ultimately looks like:**

[image]

#### Expected output would be:

```
[['UniqueData1', 'UniqueTest1', '13', '13.39%', '42.70%', 'Data', '#F8696B', '#F8696B', '#63BE7B'], ['UniqueData1', 'UniqueTest1', '14', '82%', '41.90%', 'Data', '#FFEB84', '#63BE7B', '#FFEB84'], ['UniqueData1', 'UniqueTest1', '18', '29.39%', '41%', 'Data', '#63BE7B', '#FFEB84', '#F8696B'], ['UniqueData2', 'UniqueTest2', '22.3', '44.40%', '42.30%', 'Data', '#63BE7B', '#FFEB84', '#F8696B'], ['UniqueData2', 'UniqueTest2', '4', '44.20%', '43.40%', 'Data', '#F8696B', '#F8696B', '#63BE7B'], ['UniqueData2', 'UniqueTest2', '4.1', '49%', '42.70%', 'Data', '#FFEB84', '#63BE7B', '#FFEB84'], ['UniqueData3', 'UniqueTest1', '4.45', '49.50%', '42.42%', 'Data', '#63BE7B', '#63BE7B', '#63BE7B'], ['UniqueData3', 'UniqueTest1', '4.29', '20%', '42.30%', 'Data', '#FFEB84', '#F8696B', '#FFEB84'], ['UniqueData3', 'UniqueTest1', '4.22', '25%', '41.20%', 'Data', '#F8696B', '#FFEB84', '#F8696B']]
```

#### In visual terms (strictly for show only)

```
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,13,13.39%,42.70%,Data,#F8696B,#F8696B,#63BE7B
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,14,82%,41.90%,Data,#FFEB84,#63BE7B,#FFEB84
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,18,29.39%,41%,Data,#63BE7B,#FFEB84,#F8696B
UniqueData2,UniqueTest2,22.3,44.40%,42.30%,Data,#63BE7B,#FFEB84,#F8696B
UniqueData2,UniqueTest2,4,44.20%,43.40%,Data,#F8696B,#F8696B,#63BE7B
UniqueData2,UniqueTest2,4.1,49%,42.70%,Data,#FFEB84,#63BE7B,#FFEB84
UniqueData3,UniqueTest1,4.45,49.50%,42.42%,Data,#63BE7B,#63BE7B,#63BE7B
UniqueData3,UniqueTest1,4.29,20%,42.30%,Data,#FFEB84,#F8696B,#FFEB84
UniqueData3,UniqueTest1,4.22,25%,41.20%,Data,#F8696B,#FFEB84,#F8696B
```

M4tini's answer below is very close to what I need, just looking for a way to ignore and or force a different color for certain values.

Comment: Where do I get the relation between those numbers and hex values?

Comment: @thefourtheye In excel for example: http://i.imgur.com/PIpqdXx.png which ultimately looks like this if separated: http://i.imgur.com/nY1EFti.png

Comment: Is there a special relation between the numbers\colours, or are they just used for the grouping together of similar values visually?

Comment: @M4rtini No there aren't any special relations they are grouped by dataset which is the unique group defined by merging row[0] and row[1] which in my example gives me 3 unique groups, they are simply given a visual color scheme exactly like excel does giving the highest number the green, lowest the red but on a gradient scale.

Comment: @M4rtini I've added my expected output and an example output csv (I don't want it outputting to csv, I want it to go into the list as shown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kinda works, mapValues function need to be changed to match excel. I don't know what method they use, this one seemed logical to me at least. And there are certainly more efficient\prettier ways to do this.

```
def mapValues(values):
    values = [float(i.split('%')[0]) for i in values]
    colorMap = np.array(['#F8696B', '#FFEB84', '#63BE7B'])
    #colorMap = np.array(["low", "mid", "high"])
    values = np.asarray(values)
    _, bins = np.histogram(values, 2)
    mapped = np.digitize(values, bins)
    return list(colorMap[mapped - 1])

def mapAndAdd(finalList, tempList, v1,v2,v3):
    v1 = mapValues(v1)
    v2 = mapValues(v2)
    v3 = mapValues(v3)
    for i,j in enumerate(newList):
        finalList.append(j + [v1[i] , v2[i] , v3[i]])


uniqueDataSet = set()

finalList = []
for index, DataSet in enumerate(lst):
    if (DataSet[0] + DataSet[1]) in uniqueDataSet:
        v1.append(DataSet[2])
        v2.append(DataSet[3])
        v3.append(DataSet[4])
        newList.append(DataSet)
    else:
        if (index != 0):
            mapAndAdd(finalList, newList, v1,v2,v3)

        uniqueDataSet.add(DataSet[0] + DataSet[1])
        newList = [DataSet]
        v1 = [DataSet[2]]
        v2 = [DataSet[3]]
        v3 = [DataSet[4]]

mapAndAdd(finalList, newList, v1,v2,v3)
```

Comment: That's pretty close to what I need, however it only has three color, I am looking for it to automatically generate a gradient based on the numbers for example: **http://i.imgur.com/qvvbC2y.png** or for example turning my example data into 1 dataset looks like: **http://i.imgur.com/7JxkWgu.png**

Comment: Simply adding more bins and colors to the mapValues function might be enough

Comment: @M4tini the datasets vary in size, it will map the correct color based on the size?

Comment: Yes. It creates a histogram of the values for each unique dataset. Then finds out which bin each value was placed in, and maps tha bin number to a value. So yes the size of the dataset should not matter.

Comment: @M4tini is there a way I can easily generate a list of 1-100 in color gradients from a excel file so that I don't have to go through 100 cells manually and grab the hex colors?

Comment: @M4tini, I added 50 hex colors however, I'm trying to add an extra option into it so that anything cell that is blank or has "NA" in it would be set as it's own color... ignoring the histogram.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Python with [XlsxWriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org):

```
worksheet.conditional_format('A1:A12', {'type': '3_color_scale'})
```

[image: Conditional Formatting]

See the [Working with Conditional Formats](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_conditional_formats.html) section of the documentation and [this example program](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_conditional_format.html#ex-cond-format) which demonstrates a lot of the available conditional formatting features.

Comment: The thing is the conditional formatting isn't for an excel file, I just need the hex color codes in the excel format...